# .tableExport is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

still me with the same deal..

So i'll explain it quick. I've all includes in my page so thats not it.

I'm working on visual studio.

I've created a table that i want to export in pdf or anything else. And so i'm using this :

https://github.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin

This works very well if in my code i put it like this :

```
                $('table').tableExport({ type: 'pdf', jspdf: { orientation: 'l', format: 'a3', margins: { left: 10, right: 10, top: 20, bottom: 20 }, autotable: { styles: { fillColor: 'inherit', textColor: 'inherit' }, tableWidth: 'auto' } } });
```

Obviously surrounded by  balise.

But anytime i want to put this in a button, it doesn't work !! Chrome console keep saying me this : .tableExport is not a function

How can it be possible ? It works well when i just call the script !

This is my event and my button (please if someone has something to help that would be really great !) :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#downloadPDF').on('click', function (e) {
                    console.log("test");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('table').tableExport({ type: 'csv' });

                    $('table').tableExport({
                        type: 'pdf',
                        jspdf: {
                            orientation: 'l',
                            format: 'a3',
                            margins: {
                                left: 10,
                                right: 10,
                                top: 20,
                                bottom: 20
                            },
                            autotable: {
                                styles: {
                                    fillColor: 'inherit',
                                    textColor: 'inherit'
                                },
                                tableWidth: 'auto'
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

            <button type="button" id="downloadPDF" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>*@
```

Thanks guys.

```
        <table id="table" class="table table-hover ">

            <tbody>             
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>




            <tr class="info">
                <td><b></b></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <br /><br />
                         <br /><br />
                        <br /><br />
             </tbody>           
                    </td>
                    <td><br /><br /><br /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>

        </table>

    </div>

    @* Bouton extraction *@

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

            });
        </script>
        <script>

        $('#downloadPDF').on('click', function (e) {
                    console.log("test");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('table').tableExport({
                        type: 'pdf',
                        jspdf: {
                            orientation: 'l',
                            format: 'a3',
                            margins: {
                                left: 10,
                                right: 10,
                                top: 20,
                                bottom: 20
                            },
                            autotable: {
                                styles: {
                                    fillColor: 'inherit',
                                    textColor: 'inherit'
                                },
                                tableWidth: 'auto'
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
        </script>


        <button type="button" id="downloadPDF" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>*@
```

Comment: Put the code on JSfiddle or JsBin so that I can see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I had faced this issue. This happens if the other js dependency files of tableExport.js is not included in correct order. Ensure that those files are included and that too in proper order as shown in the git hub page of it.
https://github.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin.

Comment: I've included it just like the github page. So can't be this. "This happens if the other js dependency files of tableExport.js is not included in correct order." you mean filesaver and so on ?

Comment: Is there multiple tables in markup and is table fully rendered while using the button ?

Comment: There is only one table. I put you my full code on my question. Well i've deleted the information because i can't show them, but that's te structure.

Comment: Is the whole snippet starting with document.ready is added to the page after all the plugin related javascript files.

Comment: What do you mean ? you want me to add document.ready ?

I'm not really fine with jquery. So maybe i'm forgetting something

Comment: @christian Pliso you don't need to put button click event inside document ready function. Because anyways function will execute only on button click. After taking that outside ensure all the scripts related to tableExport.js are before the script of button click.

Comment: @CijoVJ so what do i need to do ? Delete this : $('#downloadPDF').on('click', function (e) {
                    console.log("test");
                    e.preventDefault();

and just keep the function document ready ?

Comment: Don't delete.Take the button click outside document ready, that is, make your button click an independent function. and make sure it follows tableExport.js script.

Comment: do i have to keep the ready function too ? And i have to put tableExport js just before the click function ? i'll add the change to my post so you can tell me, i've made the change, is that what you want me to do ?

Comment: Well, with that i don't have error message anymore but neither the test message in the console like it should be. Nothing happens

Comment: script order - 1. jquery
2.FileSaver.min.js
3.jspdf.min.js
4.jspdf.plugin.autotable.js
5.tableExport.js
6. button click script.
$('#downloadPDF').on('click', function (e) {
  console.log("testing")
 });

Comment: follow the above order and check if you get "testing" in console. on button click. If not make sure you are not using same id "downloadPDF" for some other html tag

Comment: Found the issue put your button click script after <button> tag. for the above code.

Comment: I go testing in console if i put it after the button but if i do the same with the scritp where tableExport is in, i get the error TypeError: $(...).tableExport is not a function :(

Comment: What kind of sh*t is that ? I'm really frustrated right now, since yesterday i can't figure out why it's not executing tableExport when it is in a .on event

Comment: Did you make sure you have included jQuery? You need to include jQuery in a Script tag before includeing tableExport.

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue done.
but when i put my all  tags bottom of the file and outer  tag.
Its done it perfectly works.

I hope it will help you.